# Append result to datasource with swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm using a promise result to fill a data source and update a table view data.

I have declared:

```
var tdataSource: [FriendResponser]? //Contains de result previous to bind

    var dataSource: [FriendResponser]? { //this is the total result after append
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

But, when I try to append the result with:

```
promise.then { user in
            self.tdataSource = user
            dataSource?.append(tdataSource?)
            //self.dataSource = user
            }.catch{
                error in
                SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

But in the `dataSource?.append(tdataSource?)` is giving me the error: `_?? is not convertible to '0'`

How I can append the result data to my dataSource to display both results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extend`

`append` appends one element of the same type
`extend` appends an array of the same type

Comment: Works! and you right! `append` only can one element, mean while `extend` can append and array :)